# http request does not contain a definition for createresponse in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using .net core 2.1 , when I created controller and inherit ApiController. but in my controller method return type HttpResponseMessage and give a error given question title here is my method

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetAll")]
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public HttpResponseMessage SelectCAllCustomers()
{
    try
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<List<Customer>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, customerDetailsRepository.FindAll("SelectAllCustomers").ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asp.Net Core no longer uses that API.

Use the updated syntax

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CustomersController: Controller {

    //...

    [HttpGet("GetAll")]
    [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
    public IActionResult SelectCAllCustomers() {
        var model = customerDetailsRepository.FindAll("SelectAllCustomers").ToList();
        return Ok(model);            
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to send Custom Phrase with Status code, is it possible?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale you would most likely have to create your own result or try to edit the response yourself.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale also note the comment associated with that answer about setting ReasonPhrase

Comment: Thank you for your time but that is not working for me:) m using `.net core 2.1`

Comment: @Nkosi, sorry if I'm dumb but I'm not seeing a comment about "setting ReasonPhrase" that you mentioned. Where can I find this comment?